# Numerous exceptions thrown by base_facebook.php

Tags: facebook, ssl, curl, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have a Facebook Application which works but every day I get an exception while testing.  All exceptions are being thrown by base_facebook.php - is anyone else encountering these exceptions? Anyone has a stable base_facebook.php that they can share?

Update:
Seems like others are experiencing such exceptions as I found a bug opened with Facebook on high priority. How come nobody reported it yet on Stackoverflow?
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267344716670841

-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: connect() timed out! thrown in /home/dev-mpm/public_html/client/PHP3/base_facebook.php on line 814

Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout thrown in /home/dev-mpm/public_html/client/PHP3/base_facebook.php on line 814

Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received thrown in /home/dev-mpm/public_html/client/PHP3/base_facebook.php on line 814

Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 thrown in /home/dev-mpm/public_html/client/PHP3/base_facebook.php on line 814

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: parameters user or session key required thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/client/PHP3/base_facebook.php on line 708

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/client/PHP3/base_facebook.php on line 1053
```

Comment: Seems like you experience issues not with `base_facebook` but with your system curl or ssl libraries

Comment: The app works most of the times so not sure how curl or ssl libraries would be at fault.  I just found a high priority bug opened at Facebook where other developers have reported a similar exception.  I just edited my original question to include an update.